# Android app which scans while camera moves

Tags: android, photography, scanning

Is there an app which can scan image/text while you move camera along of paper (like real scanner does) ? OCR is not necessary. I want be able to get a single long photo of scanned surface.

In a default camera app there is panorama mode, but in order use it you should rotate phone around vertical axis, but I want to move it along a sheet (without rotation).

Comment: If there is, we would not know if it's applicable to you since you haven't provided any of your requirements.

Comment: @rrirower all what I need is to scan by moving phone, everything else is not so important.

Comment: Every camera app does that, and you get a live view. So it's a bit broad. Maybe something else is still important – and you want to save the scan, for example? If so, things like resolution, image quality, supported formats might be criteria, don't you think? And I bet there's one more: should that app produce separate images (like doing serial snaps) – or should it "stitch" them to a single file? Would you like your collection being stored/exported as PDF, or would TIFF be fine?

Comment: @Izzy (about live view) do you mean panorama ?

Comment: No – I mean the display shows you what the camera sees (as you wrote, "everything else is not so important", so in my example the scan is done and the result displayed). It was rather an ironic comment/example to make you aware of the fact that some other things *are* relevant. Thanks to your update, it now makes sense: your "wanted" description seems to match the panorama mode of e.g. "A Better Camera". There are several candidates [on my list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera), but I'm not sure which ones match your needs (never used a camera that way).